# Create navigation based on files in folder

Tags: php, html

Okay so I have my navigation for my entire website in one single file called: `navigation-sidebar` with the following code right now,

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Candy Kingdom</a></li>
</ul>
```

I then have the actual code for my website pages in the folder called: `pages`

I am wanting to create a `php foreach statement` in `navigation-sidebar` that creates the `<li> </li>` for each file in the folder pages.

I am not sure how to tell php how to read a directory and create based on that directory. I'm not wanting to type the navigation manually.

Comment: have a look at http://us1.php.net/glob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  foreach the [glob](http://php.net/glob) function:

```
foreach(glob("pages/*.html") as $page){ // to get all the extentions use "*.*"
    print('<li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="pages/'.$file.'">Candy Kingdom</a></li>');
}
```